# Compare and add the difference on new files

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I would like to compare two host files and add the differences in new file.
How can I use awk, grep, diff...

Example

```
Host1.txt

#mysrv1
78.23.2.1.3   tata.com
98.56.21.34   website.com


Host2.txt

#mysrv1
200.75.2.23    toto.com
98.56.21.34   website.com
734.2.32.1    test.com   

Hostfinal.txt

#mysrv1
98.56.21.34   website.com
78.23.2.1.3   tata.com
200.75.2.23    toto.com
734.2.32.1    test.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -ur Host1.txt Host2.txt > Hostfinal.txt
```

sort both files, unique lines only, result goes into the file

- -u = output only unique values
- -r = reverse sort order (to get the #mysrv1 at the top, may not be necessary)

Comment: @Sundeep True!  Violated rule1 'Think and then write' :-)

Answer (score 1):

if your two files have same format, this is the quick way:

```
 awk '!a[$0]++' f1 f2
```

- same format means for same ip address, the lines in f1 and f2 are **exactly same**.

Comment: @nitharrshanNadarajah then you should show this in your example.

Comment: i edit my post could you please check agian. the ip adresse was same but not by order

Comment: @nitharrshanNadarajah order is not the problem. my codes work for your edited example. give my one-liner a try on your files, check if the result is what you want.

Comment: thanks it works fine, Could you explain me whats is the '!a[$0]++'please